# WP: Вывод определенной категории на страницу c пагинацией

Tags: php, wordpress

Цель: вывести на страницу 5 постов (всего 7) определенной категории (рубрики) + пагинация, т.е. пагинация должна показывать две страницы, потому что на одной размещаем только 5.

**Вопрос по пагинации:** при данном коде пагинация показывает страницы как для всех постов (10 страниц), а мне нужно чтоб она показывала только две страницы - как это сделать?

Вообщем, код такой:

```
<div class="news__archive">
    <?php // Display blog posts on any page
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby'        => 'comment_count',
        'category'       => 22
    ] );

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="news__single">
        <div class="news__single_wrap df">
            <!-- image -->
            <?php hellpa_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <div class="news__single_text">
                <!-- link on full text -->
                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Читать далее"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                <!-- date text -->
                <p class="news__single_date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
                <!-- short text -->
                <div class="news__single_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Читать далее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    <div class="news__pagination">
        <?php if ( function_exists( 'wp_corenavi' ) ) wp_corenavi(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Для пагинации в functions.php код такой:

```
    function wp_corenavi() {
  global $wp_query;
  $total = isset( $wp_query->max_num_pages ) ? $wp_query->max_num_pages : 1;
  $a['total'] = $total;
  $a['mid_size'] = 3; 
  $a['end_size'] = 1; 
  $a['prev_text'] = '&laquo;'; 
  $a['next_text'] = '&raquo;'; 

  if ( $total > 1 ) echo '<nav class="pagination">';
  echo paginate_links( $a );
  if ( $total > 1 ) echo '</nav>';
}
```

Comment: Так у WP же есть шаблонизатор который цепляется к слагу? И можно делать шаблоны типа category-{slug} а так же к id category-{id}

Comment: Да, я видел эту схему, но хочется реализовать этот код. Буду очень признателен если кто-то поможет решить этот ребус.

Comment: Сделай свой шаблон для категории или архива, чем ты там пользуешься.... В нём сделай свой цикл и выведи записи

Comment: В целом они вроде должны падать в основной квери тебе только переоформить, изменить билдер на 5 записей на странице грубо говоря

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ!!! Чуть со стула не упал от смеха.... Короче ответ такой:

Вместо:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby'        => 'comment_count',
    'category'       => 22
] );
```

Надо такой:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby'        => 'comment_count',
        'cat'            => 22
    ] );
```

Все остальное правильное!!!